# Embedding javascript snippets: tag injection vs a complete tag

Tags: javascript, code-snippets

on the facebook developer docs, i see:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Great Web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
           ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
         }(document));
      </script>

      <div class="fb-like"></div>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Like google analytics, among many other things, this generates a script tag, and inserts it into the dom.

Why not just write `<script type="text/javascript" src="someUrl.com/etc"></script>` to begin with?

I assume its to prevent blocking behavior by loading / injecting after page load (aka async). is async the only reason??

Comment: Why not indeed. You'll have to ask Facebook. Don't be surprised if there's no sensible answer. It may be that they want the browser to download the script asyncrhronously, but browser supporrt is poor. Equivalent to just put the script element at the bottom of the page.

Comment: That's exactly right Kristian. Chris Coyier has an informative roundup of Asynchronous script loading techniques: http://css-tricks.com/thinking-async/

Comment: This is not about programming embedded systems.  Retagged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This form of loading the script adds it to the page asynchronously.

The attribute `js.async = true;` is not supported on older browsers so this is kindof a hack to make it work even on older browers.

How it works: it adds the script to the head or an already loaded part of the dom, to prevent the browser from download this script before moving on.